# Exclude boolean variables from output of describe() function from psych package

Tags: r, statistics, boolean, psych, describe

I have some data table, imported from a text file.

Then I am using `describe(table)` function from `psych` package.

It returns variances, means and so on for each variable, including booleans, which are although marked with asterisk symbol.

```
age       1  5000  66.65  6.65   67.00   66.88  7.41  44.00  79.00  35.00  -0.33   -0.39   0.13
smokes*   2  5000  1.39   0.49   1.00    1.36   0.00  1.00   2.00   1.00    0.47   -1.78   0.01
```

How to exclude boolean variables from output of `describe` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is not a good idea to name an object `table` since this is the name of a very basic function in R.

It is not possible to exclude the statistics based on logical vectors from the object returned by `describe`, since both logical vectors and factors are indicated by an `*`. A solution is to exclude all logical columns from the object passed to `describe`.

For your data frame `table`:

```
describe(table[ , !sapply(table, is.logical)])
```

Comment: Thank you! As to name of an object, I used `table` just here, to make clear what type of object it is.